# Unwanted behavior with NHibernate transactions

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, concurrency

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 application using NHibernate over a PostgreSQL database.

There is an operation on my website which takes all entities (I call them **units**) and if they satisfy certain condition, it updates one of their property (column). This whole operation is enclosed within a transaction.

Today I encountered a problem where I noticed that sometimes, (exactly) one **unit** does not get updated during the operation, even though it should (it satisfies the required condition).

Now I found out that this is because in the same time there are a lot of other requests coming to the server, which are also dealing with the **units** (for this request, it is always one **unit** which is examined and, if needed, modified).

So in one thread I have this code running:

```
ISession session = sessionBuilder.GetSession();
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var unitsToBeUpdated = session.QueryOver<Unit>()
            .Where(x => x.Status == STATUS_TRANSLATED)
            .JoinQueryOver<UnitParent>(u => u.Parent)
            .JoinQueryOver<Document>(p => p.Document)
            .Where(d => d.Job == job);

    foreach (Unit unit in unitsToBeUpdated.List<Unit>())
    {
        unit.Status = STATUS_CONFIRMED;
        session.SaveOrUpdate(unit);
    }     

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

and in a second thread I get this code running (multiple times, each time for different `unitId`)

```
Unit unit;
using (ITransaction transaction = sessionBuilder.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
{
    unit = unitRepository.GetById(unitId);
}

using (ITransaction transaction = sessionBuilder.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
{                
    unit.LastCategory = statisticsHarvester.AddWords(job, unit);  
    unitRepository.Update(unit);              
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

In this second thread, the transaction opening is shown twice because in fact these two transactions are created in different functions.

So the requests go like

```
Request A started...

Request B(unitId = 0) started...
Request B(unitId = 0) finished

Request B(unitId = 1) started...
Request B(unitId = 1) finished

....

Request B(unitId = n) started...
Request A finished
Request B(unitId = n) finished

Request B(unitId = n+1) started...
Request B(unitId = n+1) finished

....
```

Maybe I don't fully get the whole world of transactions and concurrent access, but in this situation, should it not be impossible for the first thread to update just some units? I expected the whole transaction to roll back, had something gone wrong.
What is the problem here?

Thank you.

**EDIT: Finally I solved this with "dynamic update" feature in NHibernate - in my case the two requests do not modify the same field of the entity, so it is viable.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is in here:

```
Unit unit;
using (ITransaction transaction = sessionBuilder.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
{
    unit = unitRepository.GetById(unitId);
}

using (ITransaction transaction = sessionBuilder.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
{                
    unit.LastCategory = statisticsHarvester.AddWords(job, unit);  
    unitRepository.Update(unit);              
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Here you do a read and then start a new transaction. Between the two transaction the unit can be changed in the database. In the second transaction you save the old unit back into the database. Last write wins here.

Rewrite the code like:

```
Unit unit;
using (ITransaction transaction = sessionBuilder.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
{
    unit = unitRepository.GetById(unitId); //Add lock mode in you getbyid function LockMode.Upgrade
    unit.LastCategory = statisticsHarvester.AddWords(job, unit);  
    unitRepository.Update(unit);              
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

You should also check your transaction level.

And a good pattern to implement is optimistic locking (if the transaction fails, log the error). If you have problems in your locking you will see errors in your logs, and be able to debug your code.

http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-10-transactions-and-concurrency#10%282E%296%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Pessimistic_Locking

Comment: Debating down voting your answer so you'll have 1,337 reputation :)

Comment: @peer: +1. Thank you, this was very helpful. Even after I changed the code, I still get the same problem. The default isolation level in NHibernate is `ReadCommited`. Dirty reads are not possible under this isolation level, but I think dirty read is not a problem here, are they? I think it can still happen that the two requests read an unit **U** is some order, request #1 updates **U** and then request #2 updates **U**, effectively discarding changes made by request #1. Is there a way to prevent this (updating an entity which has been changed since I last read it)?

Comment: A read will not lock the row in the database, so it is still possible for an other thread to read the row. You can also try to add a LockMode.Upgrade when you read from the database. To prevent writing to a changed record you can implement optimistic locking. This will prevent writing to a changed record. I have only seen a small part of your code, but the problem starts from two threads updating the same unit at the same time. A radical solution would be to allow only one thread at the time to run the 'read update part' of the code. This will certainly have a bad impact on your performance.

Comment: Thank you. I looked up how to do the optimistic locking in NHibernate and will give it try (and let know about the result here). However, now I tried to run the transaction of the request #2 in `Serializable` isolation level and it worked in that all **units** were correctly updated, but one of the #2-type requests ended with SQL exception: **could not serialize access due to concurrent update** which is quite reasonable. I just wanted to ask, whether it is better to use the optimistic locking (which I believe will work, but requires adding a column to DB) or `Serializable` transaction...

Answer (score 0):

+1 for peer's answer. To minimize these kind of problems consider that a transaction should enclose one operation.

So in your "second thread" try to assemble as mush as possible in that one transaction because the operation is to update the LastCategory property of the given units:

```
using (ITransaction transaction = sessionBuilder.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (Unit unit in unitRepository.GetByIds(unitIds) { //an array of unitIds or something similar
       unit.LastCategory = statisticsHarvester.AddWords(job, unit);  
       unitRepository.Update(unit);              
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it this way, each request can only work with a single unit.